# Predicting Repurchase Curves next value based on usual functional form

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, approximation

*Some definitions first:*

**Acquired customers:** Customers placing an order for their first time.

**Cohort:** Group of customers that have been acquired during the same time period.

**Repurchase:** An order placed by a customer that had previously placed at least one order.

**Repurchase Rate:** Repurchases / Acquired customers

**Repurchase Curve:** Sequence of repurchase rates for a cohort in time.

---

*The problem:*

For each cohort I have a repurchase curve.

Say we take the first 60 days to plot the repurchase curves.

Cohorts with an age of at least 60 days will have a full plot I’ll call these “Full cohorts”.

“Younger” cohorts will show a shorter line. I’ll call these incomplete cohorts.

**My objective** is to use the information of full cohorts to train a model which I can use to predict the next value of all incomplete cohorts, no matter their length. I want to take this approach given that all cohorts seem to behave in a very similar way.

The ideal scenario would be a model being able to use available information of incomplete cohorts to approximate the following repurchase curve value.

Below you can find:

1. An example of full repurchase curves [image: Full Repurchase Curves]
2. An incomplete repurchase curve (in light-blue) for which I would like to predict its next value. [image: Incomplete repurchase curve]

I have this idea but I don't know how to move further. I thought about an exponential regression, but I'm not sure how to leverage the information that's available for each incomplete curve...

What kind of model do you think would be a good choice?

Please, any suggestions, comments or alternative approaches would be much appreciated.
Thanks!